# ASP.NET MVC - Securing actions by default (without putting attributes on every action)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

So far I've seen the main advice for applying authorization rules consists of adding various attributes to actions. Which is fine if the majority of your actions don't require authorisation.

However my application entirely exists behind a login form, so for me it makes sense to have all actions require authorisation by default.

Is there a way to do this without having to annotate every method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can dictate the login via the [web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
2. You can derive all your controllers from a common base controller which either has an attribute over it, or override the `OnAuthorization` method.
3. Implement the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` in the Global.asax.

Comment: I understand web.config-based authorization isn't suitable for ASP.NET MVC... or is it? I know it "works" but that there are times when it can be skirted around, but I don't know how exactly the location="" attribute in web.config is applied to requests (it seems to be voodoo to me).

Comment: @David ASP.Net MVC is still ASP.Net, there is no way to skirt around it.

Comment: I agree with point n° 2. Write a base controller with the [Auth] attribute and if it's need, write a custom attribute for toggling it off where it applies.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 you could register a [global authorize action filter](http://blog.tallan.com/2011/02/04/global-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc-3/). If not you could define a base controller class which will be decorated with the Authorize attribute and then all your controllers will derive from this base controller.

Comment: Remember do not derive the Login controller from this base controller becasue login should have public access ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add Authorization section to your web.config file

```
<authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
```

and also, specify the login url

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Logon" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```